# Channel Names for ETW Providers

Tags: windows, winapi, event-log, etw

I'm trying to get my Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) provider manifest to register the proper channel names.  When I use the manifest (included below) I get the following results.  However, when I inspect the differences between my manifest and the results from teh All-User-Install-Agent manifest in the registry (stored in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT) I'm not seeing any reason why my keys are being displayed with the Foo-Bat-TestApp/ prefix.  How do I get rid of the prefix?  I can't remove them from the name attribute because there is already an OS component using the "Operational" name (it's a flat list in the registry).

[image: Event Viewer Snapshot]

My sample manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<instrumentationManifest
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events"
    xmlns:win="http://manifests.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/windows/events"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <instrumentation>
    <events>
      <provider name="Foo-Bar-TestApp"
                guid="{C5C633DC-FB7E-4EA0-80EC-C683FA52561C}"
                symbol="EtwProvider"
                resourceFileName="C:\Projects\ETWTest\bin\Debug\ETWTest..dll"
                messageFileName="C:\Projects\ETWTest\bin\Debug\ETWTest.dll">
        <channels>
          <channel name="Foo-Bar-TestApp/Admin"
                   chid="Admin"
                   type="Admin"
                   enabled="true" />
          <channel name="Foo-Bar-TestApp/Operational"
                   chid="Operational"
                   type="Operational"
                   enabled="true" />
          <channel name="Foo-Bar-TestApp/Debug"
                   chid="Debug"
                   type="Debug"
                   enabled="false" />
        </channels>
        <keywords>
          <keyword name="KeywordA" symbol="READ_KEYWORD" mask="0x1" />
          <keyword name="KeywordB" symbol="WRITE_KEYWORD" mask="0x2" />
        </keywords>
       <events>
          <event version="1"
                 value="1"
                 symbol="SampleEvent"
                 channel="Operational"
                 level="win:Informational"
                 message="$(string.Event.SampleEvent)"
                 keywords="KeywordA" />
        </events>
      </provider>
    </events>
  </instrumentation>
  <localization>
    <resources culture="en-US">
      <stringTable>
        <string id="Event.SampleEvent" value="This is a sample event"/>
      </stringTable>
    </resources>
  </localization>
</instrumentationManifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement required functionality you have to use symbol attribute on the channel definition. See example below:

    `<channel name="Admin" symbol="Foo-Bar-TestApp-Admin" chid="Admin" type="Admin" enabled="true" />`